# Wildcard match in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in python

```
x =  "orange".
```

The program accepts an input string.If the input string matches the wildcard pattern of x, then I perform some operation.
The pattern is

```
pattern = "#.orange.*"
```

# (hash) - can substitute for zero or more words.

*(star) - can substitute for exactly one word.

So, if my input string is "quick.orange.rabbit", then it should match. Can anyone help me how to do this in python??
I have tried -

```
import re
input_str = input("enter string")
pattern = #.orange.*
p = re.compile(pattern)
if p.match(input_str):
   # do something
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried? anything at all? an input function at least? You should show us where you're stuck so we don't have to write an entire tutorial for you, just answer your question

Comment: Will 'orange' in a matching input string always have a dot immediately before & after it?

Comment: yes. It will have always have a dot immediately before and after it.

Comment: It is basically a RabbitMQ topic exchange principle.

Comment: @OferSadan I have edited the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: `#.orange.*` is a comment, you should at least enclose it in quotes to make a string.

Comment: Define a "word". Sequences of word characters that are separated by non-word characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding the Regex idea correctly, but if I'm correct, you want to match the following:
(Zero or more words).orange.(Exactly one word)

Now I do not know if the words in the hash are seperated by spaces, periods or are just words after each other, but here are the following cases:

**Hash words separated by spaces**

```
pattern = r"(?P<hash>(\w+|\s)*)\.(?P<orange>orange)\.(?P<star>\w+)"
```

**Hash words seperated by periods**

```
pattern = r"(?P<hash>(\w+|\.)*)\.(?P<orange>orange)\.(?P<star>\w+)"
```

**Hash words just after each other**

```
pattern = r"(?P<hash>(\w*))\.(?P<orange>orange)\.(?P<star>\w+)"
```

---

If you don't want to have the (?P<>) syntax, you can also just do the following

```
pattern = r"(\w+|\s)*\.orange\.\w+"
```

Which will match against your string and tell you if it is a match, but you then can't do

```
match.group('hash')
```

To get the hash words.

Comment: But * means exactly one word. here I can see \w+ which means one or more??

Comment: All right I'd take a look at [the Python re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).  
`\w` refers to Unicode word characters: most **characters** that can be part of a word, as well as numbers and underscore. Since these are characters and not words, you use the `+` character, which indeed means 1 or more characters. Because I your _hash_ words could be more than one, I had the following syntax:  
`r"(?P<hash>(\w+|\.)*`  
Explanation: 0 or more words (`*` character), each words consists of 1 or more characters (`\w+`), or a period `|\.`

Is everything clear?

Comment: @megna Also, I made a mistake in the regex. I had the character `.`, but you have to have `\.`. As you can see in the re documentation, `.` matches any character except a newline. Whereas this did work, it means that you're going to get a lot of backtracking, as it tries to match everything, rather than just the decimal point (given by `\.`). I'd recommend you to update your code.